# cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp

how in one controller use more than one pagination?
I have this code:

```
var $paginate = array(
        'post' => array(
            'limit' => 2,
            'order' => array(
                'post.id' => 'asc',
            ),
        ),
    );
**And in the same controller need this paginate:**
    var $paginate = array(
            'post' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Post.name IS NULL or Post.id>50'),
                'limit' => 20,
                'order' => array(
                    'post.id' => 'asc',
                ),
            ),
        );
```

How in one controller use two different pagination?

Comment: Please describe in details what do you mean by "different pagination". Otherwise it is impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function otherAction() {
    $this->paginate = array('post' => array('conditions' => ...)));
    $posts = $this->paginate();
}
```

or

```
$posts = $this->paginate('Post', array('conditions' => array()));
```